# How do I embed RTF as HTML into React.JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, rtf

I have a React.JS application, basically ready. Now, I need to make pages with "terms of use" and "privacy policy" and I was wondering whether there is a way to compile time transform RichText document into HTML to get in embedded into my React.JS app. Perhaps, I could extend my `webpack` config to do this...
This way, whenever legal changes their documents, nobody will have to typeset those documents.

If you know of an existing solution, please point me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could investigate putting an automatic conversion in place via PanDoc or similar tools: [PanDoc website](http://pandoc.org/)